# Is it safe to switch between disk controllers

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sata, pata, disk-controller

I have both Windows XP and Windows 7 installed on my laptop. XP needs the IDE disk controller. While 7 needs AHCI. I have to switch between these 2 modes before I could use one of them. Does it have any effect on the health of my laptop?

Comment: Doesn't Windows 7 work under IDE mode at all? If all you're doing is changing the BIOS setting, it shouldn't affect your laptop's health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe to switch between AHCI (enhanced) and IDE (compatibility) mode, as it only changes the way the disk is accessed, but it doesn't change the data at all.

Windows 7 supports IDE mode, but it's not recommended because AHCI is faster.  You can actually download the AHCI drivers for XP if you search for your motherboard (or computer model, especially if it's a laptop).  Install those drivers, then reboot XP with AHCI enabled and it should work.